# Expose a Control of a Master Page via Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple interface like this:

```
interface IToolbarMaster {
    ToolBar Toolbar { get; }
}
```

I added this Interface to my MasterPage and moved the field declaration of the Toolbar-Control to the Code Behind File:

```
public partial class Layout : ctrls.MasterPage, IToolbarMaster {

    public global::Some.Web.Controls.ToolBar Toolbar;

    (...)

}
```

My pages need to access this Toolbar Control via the Interface (we have a `.FindMaster<IToolbarMaster>()` Method) - but the code says, `Layout` doesn't implement `IToolbarMaster`

I could implement a property like

```
public ToolBar ToolBar { get { return this.Toolbar; } } // Different name spelling
```

But this looks really odd in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, I already got the answer, I was very close.

I tried this

```
public global::Some.Web.Controls.ToolBar Toolbar { get; }
```

but it didn't work. But as I added the setter everything was fine:

```
public global::Some.Web.Controls.ToolBar Toolbar { get; set; }
```

I'm leaving this for future reference, if anyone has this problem too.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue in VB using an auto property with a default value.

```
Public Property MessagePlaceHolder() As PlaceHolder = Me.phMessage
```

Apparently that doesn't work. I had to create the property the traditional way.

```
Public ReadOnly Property MessagePlaceHolder() As PlaceHolder
    Get
        Return Me.phMessage
    End Get
End Property
```